# Need JS help on Vertical Tabs

Tags: javascript, forms

[image]I can barely cut and paste JS stuff and have not seen an example of this anywhere. I have added a vertical tab to the node admin page and I want to show either "Limited" when the value of a field in the tab is not zero or "Not limited" if it is.

I see lots of examples of using check boxes, but this is a numeric field.

Comment: Sorry but your Q is unclear to me. Show limited and unlimited where? value of which field? Maybe a screenshot with some arrows pointing at stuff would help.

Comment: In the tab itself, much like the publishing options are shown. Or where it shows "Display" or "Don't display post information." The field is "content_limit_count" which can be zero for unlimited or some number for a limit. The number is used in the code, but on the node admin page all I want to show is whether or not there is a limit.

Comment: Ugh... maybe it's just me, but I'm still not get in it.

Comment: Okay, I added a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response, your question escaped my mind.

```
(function ($) {
   (function Forever(){ // we create a function called Forever
     var grabval = $('#edit-title').val();
     $('.vertical-tab-button').each(function(){ 
       if ($(this).children().children('strong').text() == 'Content Limit'){
         if (grabval == 0 && $(this).children().children('span') == null){
           $(this).children().children('strong').after('<span class="summary">Not Limited</span>');        
         }
         else if (grabval == 0 && $(this).children().children('span') != null){
           $(this).children().children('span').html('Not Limited');        
         }
         else if (grabval != 0 && $(this).children().children('span') == null){
           $(this).children().children('strong').after('<span class="summary">Limited</span>');   
         }
         else if (grabval != 0 && $(this).children().children('span') != null){
           $(this).children().children('span').html('Limited');        
         }  
       }       
     });   
   setTimeout(Forever, 1);
   })();
})(jQuery)
```

I used the node title for mine, so if you change the title to 0 or 1 or 2 ..etc, it will change.

So all you have to do is change the `var grabtext = $('#edit-title').val();` more specifically the `#edit-title` part, and put the ID or Class name of your Maximum per time period box.

Comment: Suggestion: remove the very 1st line of your answer (no need for "sorry" ... after all: better late then never, no?).